# Do an alloy of two elements has resitivity in between of them?

Tags: electrical-resistance, material-science

If any alloy is produced from two elements, say alloy AB from A and B, then will $\rho_{A} < \rho_{AB} < \rho_{B}$ hold, where $\rho$ is symbol for resistivity ? (Assuming $\rho_{A}  < \rho_{B}$ ).

A quick check from this [source](http://alasir.com/reference/solder_alloys/) for alloys of tin and lead, holds the above relationship for most of the alloy compositions.

I doubt if this can be generalized to all the elements. If it can be, inform me. If it can be generalized for a subset of elements, inform that too. If there is no pattern at all, then why tin and lead alloy behave this way?

Comment: The resistivity will depend on too many factors:

- the macroscopic arrangement of the materials particles being mixed, 
- the materials do not chemically react, 
- the polarization induced by each macroscopic bimetallic junction.

Comment: @hypfco so, are you saying there is no any such pattern?

Comment: I am saying there should be a range of metals and procedures for which a simple relationship could be obtained, but in the simple general it could not be directly applicable. I think the question should be narrowed including all the possible effects which are affecting the process, so the question can be answered.